# How to get Employee wise tasks count in laravel along

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I want to get each employees task count in a month and integrate into bar chart,i managed to get total count of tasks based in a month i am confused how to do that user based,let's say i have 10 employees,i need how many tasks each user have and show into a barchart along with task count and name of the employees

i did kind of like this i am not sure the logic is correct or not,i have no idea why i did this.but help would be appreciated

```php
$user_tasks = DB::table('tasks')
    ->select(DB::raw("MONTHNAME(tasks.created_at) as month_name"))
    ->join('users', 'tasks.assigned_to', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where(['users.role_id', '=', auth()->user()->role_id])
    ->whereYear('tasks.created_at', date('Y'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTHNAME(tasks.created_at)"))
    ->get();

 
$labels = $user_tasks->keys();
$data = $user_tasks->values();
```

##### Error thrown

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select MONTHNAME(tasks.created_at) as month_name from `tasks` inner join `users` on `tasks`.`assigned_to` = `users`.`id` where (`0` = users.role_id and `1` = = and `2` = 1) and year(`tasks`.`created_at`) = 2023 group by MONTHNAME(tasks.created_at))

##### Employee/User Migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->nullable()->unique();
        $table->date('date_of_joining')->nullable();
        $table->date('dob')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role_id')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('status')->default(0);
    });
}
```

##### Tasks migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        // $table->integer('task_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('deadline_date')->nullable();
        $table->integer('assigned_by');
        $table->integer('assigned_to');
        $table->integer('follow_up')->nullable();
        $table->integer('priority')->default(1);
        $table->integer('work_status')->default(1);
        $table->integer('status')->default(0);
        $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
        $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('status_updated_date')->nullable();
        $table->index('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In this `assigned_to` column saves the `user_id` (`id` in `user` table). I want to get the result like this

```php
lables varibale = ['EmpName 1', 'EmpName 2', 'EmpName 3', 'EmpName 4'];
count_of_each_user_task = ['5', '8', '2', '6']
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$user_tasks = DB::table('tasks')
    ->selectRaw("CONCAT(users.name, ' (EmpName ', users.id, ')') as employee_name, COUNT(*) as task_count")
    ->join('users', 'tasks.assigned_to', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.role_id', '=', auth()->user()->role_id)
    ->whereYear('tasks.created_at', date('Y'))
    ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.name')
    ->get();

$labels = $user_tasks->pluck('employee_name')->toArray();
$count_of_each_user_task = $user_tasks->pluck('task_count')->toArray();
```

You have a couple of issues with your query try this one. Let me one if it will not work

Comment: Thanks for the headsup,there is some problem when i use where condition `->where('users.role_id', '=', auth()->user()->role_id)` i am getting 1 details it was ok,if i want to retrive all data i need to comment this line also this is year wise right,i need some with monthly wise,but it fine @Adnan Shafi

Comment: If you don't have relations then don't need to make relations your code will work fine with join as well. But in the future try to use relations it helps you to write the query in an easier way and its way more easy then query builder

Comment: After getting the data in $user_tasks add this code 
`// Extract the employee names with the month they belong to as a key $labels = $user_tasks->map(function ($item) { return $item->employee_name . ' (Month ' . $item->month_number . ')'; })->toArray(); // Extract the task counts with the month they belong to as a key $count_of_each_user_task = $user_tasks->map(function ($item) { return $item->task_count; })->toArray(); `